# execute code only on first document open

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm looking for a way to execute some vba code in my Word document, but only when the specific document is first opened. Is this possible? Is this possible to store somewhere a global variable that will handle a value between opening/closing the single document?

Comment: what do you mean by `first opened`? open `first together with other documents` or open `for the first time`?

Comment: open for the first time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to store such a variable. A simple string can be added as a document variable with:

```
'Create the variable
ThisDocument.Variables.Add "VariableName", "VariableValue"

'Read the variable
Debug.Print ThisDocument.Variables("VariableName")
```

This variable will be attached to the document and be available through VBA. You can also add a so-called custom document property that is available various places in the Word user interface (and used for additional purposes). For info on adding custom document properties, refer to the following article:

[How to use a single VBA procedure to read or write both custom and built-in Document Properties](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/MixedDocProps.htm)